# Find all options defined by a given package

Tags: r, namespaces

Is it possible to find all the options defined by a given package?  Or, is it necessary to take the difference in options before and after loading a package?

Answer (score 1):

To you first question:

`.Options` shows all the options currently set. If you'd like to find those of a certain package, you could `grep` the options with the name of the package in the option name. For example for `dplyr`:

```
.Options[grep('dplyr', names(.Options))]
```

gives

```
$dplyr.strict_sql
[1] FALSE

$dplyr.print_min
[1] 10

$dplyr.print_max
[1] 20

$dplyr.show_progress
[1] TRUE
```

I'm not sure if this will work with all packages.

Comment: I would suppose so, yes. Your own solution would (should) work in the general case.